# Buffered Image from string

Tags: java, loops, bufferedimage

I am attempting to create an image based on string with RGB color values assigned on new lines. But for whatever reason the pixels are being placed in the wrong spots creating this odd chevron pattern. Clearly the issue is in how I am increasing the values but I can't seem to find the issue.

I've also confirmed multiple different ways that there is nothing wrong with the string

[Chevron pattern I was talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJTlb.png)

```
  static void AddPixels(String Data){
      Scanner Scan = new Scanner(Data);

      ArrayList<Integer> Table = new ArrayList<>();

      while (Scan.hasNextLine() && !(XCount == XTotal)){
         Scanner LineScan = new Scanner(Scan.nextLine());
         while (LineScan.hasNext()){
            Table.add(LineScan.nextInt());
         }
         if (Table.size() == 3){
            Image.setRGB(XCount,YCount, new Color(Table.get(0),Table.get(1),Table.get(2),255).getRGB());
         }
         else{
            Image.setRGB(XCount,YCount, new Color(0,0,0,0).getRGB());
         }
         Table.clear();
         YCount++;
         if (YCount == YTotal){
            YCount = 0;
            XCount++;
            System.out.println(Math.floor(((double)XCount/XTotal)*100));
         }     
      }
      //System.out.println("Finished");
      if (XCount >= XTotal){
      System.out.println("Runnin");
         try{
            File ImageFile = new File("TestImage.png");
            ImageIO.write(Image, "png", ImageFile);
         }
         catch(IOException e)
         {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
         }
      }

}
```

Comment: Verify that your `x`/`y` coordinates are represented correctly (aren't flipped in the data) and that the values are not been updated outside of the `AddPixels` method while the image is been updated

Comment: Images are usually stored horizontal row after horizontal row, i.e (x=0,y=0), (x=1,y=0)...(x=width-1,y=0), (x=0,y=1)... Are you sure you haven't inverted X and Y here ? (your code is reading one vertical column after the other)

Comment: @FBergo Can confirm I have not flipped/inverted the data. It is vertical columns.

Comment: @MadProgrammer They are not flipped and are not being updated outside of AddPixels

Comment: @A.J.Steinhauser then the likely errors are either a) your YTotal and/or XTotal are off by one or b) XCount not properly initialized to 0 before the loop starts. Shouldn't there be a `XCount=0;` before your while loop ?

Comment: @FBergo There is a global XCount =0 and YCount=0 because this method is called multiple times as the string is fed in. As for the Total variables... I do not see how they could be off by 1 as this is the only place those variables are being altered

Answer (score 1):

You're updating your y-coordinate each time you loop (for each of R, G, and B), and painting a black pixel 2/3rds of the time (the `else` block in your code).

If I understand your problem statement correctly, the file looks like:

```
200
100
0
```

where `200` is the R value, `100` is the B value, and `0` is the G value, for each pixel.

If this is the case, you need to be updating your Y value only every third value read from the file - and not painting black pixels at all.

Comment: No the file looks like this 0  255 223 in a single line the else statement handles lines where there is only 1 int value which tells me if it is transparent or not

Comment: It sounds like you need to read the transparency value, then, and set the alpha channel correctly. Right now, you're printing a (transparent) black pixel, not setting the alpha for the printed pixel.

Comment: In other words, you're printing and extra pixel 1/2 of the time, not 2/3rds of the time.

Comment: For this image either the pixel is transparent or it is not. In the input string colored pixels come in as String = String + "\t" + R + "\t" + G + "\t" + B + "\n". And transparent pixels come in as String = String  + 1 + "\n". Its not worth wasting the limited data I have on pixels that are transparent anyways so I just denote it with a single int so that the loop can register it as a new pixel

Comment: Sounds like this probably isn't the issue, then. Your output looks like you're skipping chunks of Y-space, of size about YTotal / 2. Are you processing this in chunks somehow? I recommend taking a close look at your global state. There's almost certainly an error in how you're (possibly not) resetting it between passes.